# How to change CKEditor language from javascript at runtime?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In my application locale can be set dynamically so same behavior i want in the CKEditor , ex if in my app i change locale from EN to DA , i want same to be done in CKEditor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this during the runtime. The only way is to `destroy()` the instance first, and then create another one with different `config.language` setup.

This is how the official [UI Languages](http://ckeditor.com/demo#localization) demo works.